# ./src/index.js Attempted import error: './App.js' does not contain a default export (imported as 'App')

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs

Below is the index.js code. Below error 
./src/index.js
Attempted import error: './App.js' does not contain a default export (imported as 'App')
How to solve this?

Comment: Please show your code

Answer (score 4):

I guess your code was like this,since I cant see your code I am attaching mine.See at the bottom line of the code,add that export default app line in your code as mentioned,You'll good to go then I believe.

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.</p>
        <a className="App-link"href="https://reactjs.org"target="_blank"rel="noopener noreferrer" >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: I dont think you need `export default App;` if you are switching to react hooks. I have this issue but is not supposed to have `export default App;`.

Answer (score 3):

At the bottom of the 'App.js' file, add this line:

```
export default App;
```